# How get UniqueIdRange on MailKit?

Tags: imap, mailkit

To be able to get all the emails in a conversation, in order to obtain the e-mail in order, and so display them in the same way gmail displays.
already thanks for listening.
I tried this

```
  Iseen = box.Search(SearchQuery.NotSeen);
  UniqueIdRange idRange = Iseen as UniqueIdRange;
```

But UniqueIdRange is private and not know how I can get it.

Answer (score 0):

box.Search() will generally return a `UniqueIdSet`, not `UniqueIdRange`.

In fact, I don't think it ever returns a `UniqueIdRange`.